# Why do I get a TypeError when I do my logic in a property, but not in __init__?

Tags: python, function

```
class MyClass(object):

     def __init__(self, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3):
         self.parameter1 = parameter1
         self.parameter2 = parameter2
         self.parameter3 = parameter3

         self.new_parameter = 60 * parameter1 * parameter2

     @property
     def variable1(self):
         return 1.0 / (1.0 / self.new_parameter + 0.5)

     def calc_x(self, t):
         self.x = (self.variable1 + t) * (t / self.new_parameter)
```

As you can see *new_parameter* is defined in init() so far. I'd now like to change the calculation of *new_parameter* depending on an another variable e.g. y and an if-else statement

If i delete `self.new_parameter = 60 * parameter1 * parameter2` and add the following before @property

```
    def new_parameter(self, y):

        if (120 < y & y < 230):
            self.new_parameter = 60 * self.parameter1 * self.parameter2 * (self.parameter3 / 2)
        else: 
            self.new_parameter = 60 * self.parameter1 * self.parameter2
```

```
File "Path\script.py", line 189, in variable1
    return 1.0 / (1.0 / self.new_parameter + 0.5)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'method'
```

Could someone please help? How can i change the definition of *new_parameter* to a more dynamic approach meeting my requirements? Should i include the if-else statement just inside the init()?

Comment: Why isn't `new_parameter` also a property? Or if not, why don't you *call* the method?

Comment: In `if (120 < y & y < 230):` '&' is bitwise and.  Think you meant `if (120 < y and y < 230):`  but even better you should use:  `if (120 < y  < 230):`

Comment: ...as Darryl said, if you just refer to `self.new_parameter` and don't use `@property` in defining `new_parameter`, then you're referring to the function itself; and you can't divide a number by a function.